# How to create a universal (script) file for a Mac, based on several Terminal commands

Tags: command-line, script

I have several Terminal commands I use for troubleshooting purposes, by typing them in one by one into the terminal window.

These commands require the user's password to be entered.

I'm looking for a way to create a universal (script) file with these commands. I want to be able to run the file on a Mac just by double-clicking on it or dragging the file over the Terminal icon.

I have never done anything like this before. Is there any way to create such a script? Please advise.

Comment: Do you mean to ask that you want to run a  script **without** having the user enter their password?

Comment: @Allan I want to run _one file_ instead of _multiple commands_.

Running it without having the user enter their password at least once would be good, but most likely impossible if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That's definitely possible unless you need to do something that requires admin -- see my answer below

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you're after, but I found it very effective. You could use `alias` e.g. `alias ns="sudo netstat -tulpn"`. You could even put these in `@reboot` lines on Crontab if you wanted them on every boot. Now I can just type `ns`. Bliss.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Short answer

A `.command` script should do the trick

---

### Step-by-step

1. Open TextEdit and create a new file
2. Convert it to plain text by clicking Format > Make Plain Text
3. Add your commands, one per line.
   For example, you could do:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir myCoolFolder
cd myCoolFolder
```

4. Run `chmod u+x ~/Desktop/myCommandScript.command` in your terminal, where `~/Desktop/myCommandScript.command` is the path to your script. This will give the terminal permission to run the file.
5. You're done!  Double-click the file to run. Dragging over the terminal icon will also work.

### Notes:

- If you need to do something that requires root (admin) access, you can prefix your command with `sudo`. When the script runs, you'll have to enter your password (and be an administrator)
- If the end user isn't an administrator, but you need to do something that required root access, you can use `su someAdminName`, which will perform the command as `someAdminName` (you'll need his password).

<sub>You can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking) on Stack Overflow for a bit more information.</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to make a command file not to log out? I want to have a command file which opens the terminal with predefined path variable.

Answer (score 11):

A script is just a series of commands, so you could put it into a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

command 1
command 2
command 3
```

Now, this all depends on the they types of command and whether or not they require user intervention.

However, if you are getting diagnostic info, for example, you can have a script that does

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get SMART status of main drive
diskutil info disk0 | grep -i smart

# Get the model of the machine in question
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep -i Identifier
```

Those are just to examples.  Keep in mind that any output generated, will get sent to the console (screen).  However, you can redirect the output to a file by appending `>> /path/to/outputfile.txt` at the end of each command so you have a file which you can parse once the file has finished running.

You can name the file `diagnostics.sh` and place it anywhere you like.  Just make sure you make it executable by issuing the command `chmod +x diagnostics.sh` and use `./diagnostics.sh` to execute it or **double click on it to run it if it's saved to your desktop**.